# Building Lua for both i386 & x86_64 architecture?

Tags: c++, lua, x86-64, i386

I've been building some Lua scripts to automate certain functions and configurations that I can use with my audio VST plug-ins. The scripts themselves work fine, tested in a separate project embedded in C++.

However, due to VST and VSTGUI needing to be build against the 10.6 SDK with Architectures set to Standard 32-bit/64-bit (and Valid architectures include i386 & x86_64), when I integrate it into the VST plug-in project, it ignores liblua.a for the i386 architecture, causing obvious linking errors.

Note: I can build the VST plug-ins for 64-bit only and eliminate the i386 arch, but then the plug-in won't load in some hosts.  I think this has to do with some hosts still implementing only Carbon-based UI and how this works with VSTGUI.

Anyway, what kind of solutions exist for this problem?  I can build Lua for either architecture, but not both.  Unless I put them in separate directories and somehow tell Xcode about that?

It's not really a critical thing, but I'd like to be able to script some common elements between plug-ins.  Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you build Lua for both architectures and then `lipo` them together into one archive?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `lipo`. My knowledge in the architecture department isn't great. That sounds like what I'm looking for though. Thanks. I suppose I could always just include the source in the project as well.